# Exception on streaming the audio on android media player, on okhttp buffering

Tags: android, android-mediaplayer, audio-streaming, okhttp

```
E/JavaBinder: *** Uncaught remote exception!  (Exceptions are not yet supported across processes.)
    java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException: length=8192; index=8192
     at com.android.okhttp.okio.Buffer.writeByte(Buffer.java:973)
     at com.android.okhttp.internal.Platform.concatLengthPrefixed(Platform.java:212)
     at com.android.okhttp.internal.Platform.configureTlsExtensions(Platform.java:116)
     at com.android.okhttp.internal.io.RealConnection.connectTls(RealConnection.java:187)
     at com.android.okhttp.internal.io.RealConnection.connectSocket(RealConnection.java:149)
     at com.android.okhttp.internal.io.RealConnection.connect(RealConnection.java:112)
     at com.android.okhttp.internal.http.StreamAllocation.findConnection(StreamAllocation.java:184)
     at com.android.okhttp.internal.http.StreamAllocation.findHealthyConnection(StreamAllocation.java:126)
     at com.android.okhttp.internal.http.StreamAllocation.newStream(StreamAllocation.java:95)
     at com.android.okhttp.internal.http.HttpEngine.connect(HttpEngine.java:281)
     at com.android.okhttp.internal.http.HttpEngine.sendRequest(HttpEngine.java:224)
     at com.android.okhttp.internal.huc.HttpURLConnectionImpl.execute(HttpURLConnectionImpl.java:461)
     at com.android.okhttp.internal.huc.HttpURLConnectionImpl.getResponse(HttpURLConnectionImpl.java:407)
     at com.android.okhttp.internal.huc.HttpURLConnectionImpl.getResponseCode(HttpURLConnectionImpl.java:538)
     at com.android.okhttp.internal.huc.DelegatingHttpsURLConnection.getResponseCode(DelegatingHttpsURLConnection.java:105)
     at com.android.okhttp.internal.huc.HttpsURLConnectionImpl.getResponseCode(HttpsURLConnectionImpl.java:26)
     at android.media.MediaHTTPConnection.seekTo(MediaHTTPConnection.java:212)
     at android.media.MediaHTTPConnection.getSize(MediaHTTPConnection.java:374)
     at android.media.IMediaHTTPConnection$Stub.onTransact(IMediaHTTPConnection.java:81)
     at android.os.Binder.execTransact(Binder.java:731)
```

This exception occurs on android media player streaming and buffering, the player got stuck on the same position for unusual period of time and sometimes forever.

Comment: share you code which is doing this work, means where the exception is occurring, that would give better idea

Answer (score 2):

I don't think there's much you can do. It's [been reported](https://github.com/square/okhttp/issues/3938) to the okhttp devs. But, as they point out, the error is with the internally packaged version of okhttp that is included with android. There's no bug with square's externally developed version, so they have rightfully closed the issue as a non-issue.

The bug has been [reported to google](https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/66933611), but it doesn't look like any action has been taken in the last almost 2 years.

Perhaps you could include the newer, upstream version of okhttp from square in your project and somehow tell `MediaHTTPConnection` to use the `okhttp3` implementation of `HttpURLConnection`. There's the [OkUrlFactory](http://square.github.io/okhttp/3.x/okhttp-urlconnection/okhttp3/OkUrlFactory.html) that could be used with java's [URL.setURLStreamHandlerFactory](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/net/URL.html#setURLStreamHandlerFactory-java.net.URLStreamHandlerFactory-). However that's deprecated and it might not be a good idea to override the built-in url stream handler logic.

In fact, it's been removed from recent versions of `okhttp`. The dev who removed it did make an [ObsoleteUrlFactory.java](https://gist.github.com/swankjesse/dd91c0a8854e1559b00f5fc9c7bfae70) that you can copy/paste yourself into your project and use as:

```
OkHttpClient okHttpClient = new OkHttpClient();
URL.setURLStreamHandlerFactory(new ObsoleteUrlFactory(okHttpClient));
```